Vaadin alternative to window.function = funtion() {}
This is an extension to this question

For a couple of months, I am writing JavaScript functions that I constantly run using my Vaadin components with method executeJs().
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("myFunction()");

So am I wondering if there are other alternative ways of exporting JS functions from .js files, other than:
window.myFunction = function myFunction() {
   ....
}


I tried to export the function, by importing the file itself, using both annotations @JsModule and @JavaScript, but without any success.
@PageTitle("Dashboard")
@JavaScript("./themes/light_theme/components/javascript/myFile.js")
public class DashboardView extends Div {

    public DashboardView() {
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("myFunction()");
    }

}



Just in case, this is an X-Y-problem, would you mind adding what purpose those functions fulfill and what the calls are supposed to trigger?

Yes, this definitely feels like an X/Y problem: "how do I use something technical to achieve something technical" instead of "how do I achieve a concrete goal". And more specifically to the original post, there are different ways I can think of like element methods/properties/events, Connector pattern (see Grid), and others, but writing about all of them feels like a waste of effort if the original asker just needs one of them.
